# Webpack: Bundle several js framework into one bundle?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm trying to understand the purpose of webpack. I'm intending to use `fixed-data-table` from React and it has to be processed through webpack and transformed with Babel as it uses `require` function which otherwise can't be processed by the browser.

To output a bundle.js file, could I include, say, several frameworks in one bundle? I.e. Bootstrap, React, React-dom, and other frameworks? As far as I can tell in the documentation, you can only input one .js file and process it into a bundle.js - or am I wrong? Are there examples of importing several frameworks into one webpack configuration file, and outputting just one Bundle.js? I haven't been able to google myself to that point. Seems like most people process just one framework to one bundle, which doesn't seem intuitive to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webpack, literally takes all your dependencies and mashes it into one big file known as the ultimate `bundle.js`

There is no limit (other than the space of your hard drive) to how many frameworks you can include in one bundle, Webpack just needs to be aware that this dependency is in use and needs to be required. Depending on your build configurations, Webpack should find these immediately after traversing your directory.

The easiest method is to register the framework via. `require` or `import` call in your Babel ES6 files. If this is not possible, I suggest reading the documentation on RequireJS that is an alternate method to register them.

Comment: I'm just finding the syntax of the webpack config file a bit difficult to comprehend. Do you have to define a loader, i.e. `babel-loader` for every module? I've tried to find examples of the webpack config where people load many modules, i.e. bootstrap, react, react-dom and other JS frameworks; But every example I google, they just show examples of importing one specific framework, a 1:1 rate between input and output, which I can't use for much.

Comment: Could you post your config file perhaps? Babel should be able to digest all those

Comment: I'll do an attempt in taking all my modules and processing them. I'll edit it into my question in an hour or two. Thanks :)